# Jquery - hasclass after delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if an element has a class after some time. Like delay. Basically the class is being added to the element by some other function. So If I check the `hasClass` on that clicked element it returns false.

```
var check_selected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
if ( $(this).hasClass('selected').delay(500) ) {
  console.log(check_selected);
}
```

This is what I am trying but I want to know if we can add delay to `hasClass`, or any other way to achieve this. But it is not working

**As per answers suggested I tried this -**

```
var check_selected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
setTimeout(function(){
  if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
    console.log(check_selected);
  }
}, 500);
```

But no outcome now in console.

Just to update -

The class is being applied on click, and the same click I basically wants to know if the class is applied, so I am using hasclass. Is there any other way out, or am I doing it wrong

**EDIT -**

```
var _this = this;
                var check_selected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
                setTimeout(function(){
                  if ( $(_this).hasClass('selected') ) {
                     console.log(check_selected);
                  }
                }, 5000);
```

I am trying this but still getting false

**UPDATE -**

```
var checkSelected =  setInterval(function(){ 
                var check_selected = $(_this).hasClass('selected');
                if(check_selected) {
                 clearInterval(checkSelected);
                }
                console.log(check_selected);
              }, 500);
```

This worked!!

Comment: You can use setTimeOut(function(){ },time);

Comment: can you share how?

Comment: MDN has many examples

Comment: can you add whole event code?

Comment: inside the setTimeout function this object will refer to the current of object of setTimeout. Use this var currObj = this;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
var check_selected = $(currObj ).hasClass('selected');
        if ($(currObj).hasClass('selected')) {
            console.log(check_selected);
        } 
     },500); updated my answer. you can check it below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `setTimeout` for simulating the delay. And if you want to test this repeatedly until you get it selected you can try `setInterval(function(){}, interval)`. You need to call `clearInterval` if you want to stop calling the function.

```js
$("#test").on("click", function(){
  const component = $(this);
  
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    component.addClass("selected");
  }, 600);

  setTimeout(function(){ 
    var check_selected = component.hasClass('selected');
    console.log(check_selected);
  }, 500);

  var checkSelected =  setInterval(function(){ 
    var check_selected = component.hasClass('selected');
    if(check_selected) {
     clearInterval(checkSelected);
    }
    console.log(check_selected);
  }, 500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Check my class</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `setTimeout` its javascript function that does callback execution after the `miliseconds` passed in as second parameter

```
var check_selected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
setTimeout(function(){
  if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
     console.log(check_selected);
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: setTimeOut is not a function is the error that comes

Comment: sorry, there was a typo. correct name is 'setTimeout', and I typed 'setTimeOut', corrected the example

Comment: No results in console now

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer function

```
var currObj = this;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
var check_selected = $(currObj ).hasClass('selected');
        if ($(currObj).hasClass('selected')) {
            console.log(check_selected);
        } 
     },500);
```

Comment: setTimeOut is not a function is the error that comes

Comment: In SetTimeOut function O should be small setTimeout

Comment: No results in console now

Comment: If you see the class is being applied on click, and the same click I basically wants to know if the class is applied, so I am using hasclass. Is there any other way out, or am I doing it wrong

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle in share the link

Comment: setInterval worked, thanks. I have added my code in question.